# How should I do the following joins to get desired result?

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join

I have three tables. table1, table2, and table3. 
[image]

So, the attributes **object**, **R1**, and **R2** in table1 correspond to the object names in table2
"yahoo", "email", and "ping". And **R3** corresponds to the table3 u-id's name "Jake".

Now I need to JOIN table1 with table2 3 times and with table3 once in order to get the following table:

[image]

I have heard that I need to use LEFT JOIN but cannot get the desired result. Any help will be appreciated.  
Also the new table should be created by doing just one (big) query.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        e.name object,
        a.date,
        b.name R1,
        c.name R2,
        d.`u-name` R3
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.r1 = b.object
        INNER JOIN table2 c
            ON a.r2 = c.object
        INNER JOIN table2 e
            ON a.object = e.object
        INNER JOIN table3 d
            ON a.r3 = d.`u-id`
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

The query above that uses `INNER JOIN` is suitable only `table1` if all fields are *not nullable*. When one of them are *nullable* and you want to return all list from `table1`, use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

---

*"..Also the new table should be created by doing just one (big) query."*

```
CREATE TABLE tableNameHere(col1 INT,....) -- list of columns
AS
SELECT  a.ID,
        e.name object,
        a.date,
        b.name R1,
        c.name R2,
        d.`u-name` R3
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.r1 = b.object
        INNER JOIN table2 c
            ON a.r2 = c.object
        INNER JOIN table2 e
            ON a.object = e.object
        INNER JOIN table3 d
            ON a.r3 = d.`u-id`
```

- [CREATE TABLE...SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: Are not you missing one more JOIN? Like on "objects"?

Comment: I have a question. How can I use JOINs so that at the end the result will be: all table1 attrs + yahoo + email + ping + Jake ???

Comment: *"..the result will be: all table1 attrs + yahoo + email + ping + Jake ???* -- I can't understand it. What do you exactly mean? can you give a screenshot just like you did above?

Comment: Does your query at the top return the "exact result" table I showed above? If yes then never mind...I was told that left joins should be used